# Shrink a Windows VM in XenServer

Tags: hard-drive, xenserver, citrix, shrink, ovf

I faced a problem. I deployed a VM by size of 500GB on Citrix XenServer and now I want to shrink it, because I don't have enough space for snapshots. Now I want to perform an export/import to do this. I'm wondering if it's possible to import the OVF or OVA image on a smaller Virtual HD? or HD should be the same size?

Answer (score 1):

In XenServer the process is to use XenConvert. (You convert with a shrinked HDD, and you re-import the image into the XenServer)

Please see that KB. [How to Resize a XenServer Virtual Disk](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX123620)

The KB was created in 2014, but in old XenServer that tip worked. The tip state to use XenConvert 2+, but in 2011 it was already released.

KB's text:

> To complete the following procedure, you need the access to Access to
>   XenConvert 2.x.
>
> 1.Download and install XenConvert on the Windows VM.
>
> 2.Attach a secondary disk that is 205 percent times the size of the existing VDI. The secondary drive is to be used as temporary space for
>   XenConvert.
>
> 3.Format the secondary disk with an NTFS file system and add a drive letter to the disk.
>
> 4.Open XenConvert and click Next.
>
> User-added image
>
> 5.Adjust the free space size as the following:
>
> •Example for original size: 14406
>
> User-added image
>
> •Example for New size: 5000
>
> User-added image
>
> Description of the fields in the preceding figures:
>
> •Used Space: The space currently being used in the VDI.
>
> •Free Space: The new size for the VDI. So if you want to make it 10GB,
>   you change the value to 10240 MB.
>
> •Unallocated space: The additional space you give to the VM and that
>   is displayed as unallocated space.
>
> •Capacity: The value in the last row is the VM VDI total size:
>
> User-added image
>
> Proceed with the XenConvert utility to create a disk to import later
>   or to create the new VDI on the XenServer.

Answer (score 0):

I almost got my answer from Citrix manual:

> When you create an OVF package, the virtual hard disk images are, by default, allocated the same
>   amount of space as the exported VM. For example, a VM that is allocated 26 GB of space will have a
>   hard disk image that consumes 26 GB of space, regardless of whether or not the VM actually requires it.

So, I can't shrink it in this way!
The link below suggests a technique:
[How to Shrink a Windows VM in XenServer](https://web.archive.org/web/20161031001050/http://adrianotto.com/2012/04/how-to-shrink-a-windows-vm-in-xenserver/)

Comment: This is an example of why link-only answers are bad.  The link went away and had to be replaced with the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to first shrink the related disk from Windows. Then try to shrink it from XenServer.

Comment: Currently xenserver does not support shrinking VDI's.